# Magento - Catalog - No products show unless ? is used

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, catalog

Magento 1.9

I created a custom url rewrite.

```
category/tripods => catalog/category/view/id/809
```

I have checked and both the above work the same.
This is site wide, same with all category sections.

When I enter `my-site.com/category/tripods` No products show, I do see the layered navigation / drilldown attributes and categories.

When I enter `my-site.com/category/tripods?` The page works as expected.

The ? is triggering something I am not finding.

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category
    [_eventObject:protected] => category
    [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category
    [_useFlatResource:protected] => 
    [_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => custom_design
            [1] => custom_design_from
            [2] => custom_design_to
            [3] => page_layout
            [4] => custom_layout_update
            [5] => custom_apply_to_products
        )

    [_treeModel:protected] => 
    [_urlModel:protected] => 
    [_defaultValues:protected] => Array
        (
            [url_path] => catalog/tripods
        )

    [_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array
        (
            [url_path] => 1
        )

    [_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
    [_isReadonly:protected] => 
    [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_collection
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 809
            [entity_type_id] => 3
            [attribute_set_id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 3
            [created_at] => 2014-12-17T17:57:38-08:00
            [updated_at] => 2015-04-27 19:07:29
            [path] => 1/2/3/809
            [position] => 3
            [level] => 2
            [children_count] => 13
            [name] => Tripods
            [url_key] => tripods
            [meta_title] => 
            [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
            [custom_design] => 
            [page_layout] => home
            [url_path] => catalog-33/tripods.html
            [is_active] => 1
            [include_in_menu] => 1
            [landing_page] => 
            [is_anchor] => 1
            [custom_use_parent_settings] => 1
            [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
            [description] => 
            [meta_keywords] => 
            [meta_description] => 
            [custom_layout_update] => 
            [available_sort_by] => 
            [custom_design_from] => 
            [custom_design_to] => 
            [filter_price_range] => 
            [path_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 809
                )

        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [store_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 809
            [entity_type_id] => 3
            [attribute_set_id] => 3
            [parent_id] => 3
            [created_at] => 2014-12-17T17:57:38-08:00
            [updated_at] => 2015-04-27 19:07:29
            [path] => 1/2/3/809
            [position] => 3
            [level] => 2
            [children_count] => 13
            [name] => Tripods
            [url_key] => tripods
            [meta_title] => 
            [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
            [custom_design] => 
            [page_layout] => home
            [url_path] => catalog-33/tripods.html
            [is_active] => 1
            [include_in_menu] => 1
            [landing_page] => 
            [is_anchor] => 1
            [custom_use_parent_settings] => 1
            [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
            [description] => 
            [meta_keywords] => 
            [meta_description] => 
            [custom_layout_update] => 
            [available_sort_by] => 
            [custom_design_from] => 
            [custom_design_to] => 
            [filter_price_range] => 
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I remove .html from categories in `system > configuration > catalog > search engine optimizations`
cleared the cache and re-indexed.

`[url_path] => catalog-33/tripods.html` 
Still shows .html and why the -33 ?

Has anyone run into this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not help much directly, but may be a good reminder about forgotten code.

Teddy Dong's suggestion lead me back to the system configuration where I turned on "Easy Template Path Hints" by MagePsycho Extensions. Then I could see all the blocks, I thought my custom 2column-calalog.phtml template was not processing but it was. That lead me to go back over all the code in that file. There I found old code that would display static blocks depending on the query string, I removed it and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I not entirely sure but Magneto(磁) need the system configurations

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it indirectly lead me to the answer.